# How to replace multiple spaces in VBA with a single space using regex?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have an account statement that needs to be cleansed before doing some work with SQL. I've used a RegEx pattern to remove any punctuation and thought I could also use this to match excessive whitespace between words but I'm having trouble with the replace section of my VBA script.

So far I have:

```
   Sub RemoveSpace()
Dim cell As Range
Range("A2:C2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  .Pattern = "[\s{2,0}]"
  .Global = True
  For Each cell In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    cell.Value = .Replace(cell.Value, " ")
  Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

Although this script matches the spaces it doesn't replace them with just a single space. I think what happens is that Excel replaces each single space it matches with another space rather than treating multiple spaces as "one". Is there a way I could remove all of the multiple spaces and replace them with a single space?

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! Could you just explain why removing the zero and square brackets made a difference?

Comment: See below. Also, `\s{2,0}` is an invalid pattern, just try it at https://regex101.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[\s{2,0}]` pattern matches any single whitespace, `{`, `2`, `,`, `0` or `}` chars since these are inside a character class, inside `[...]`. See the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) reference.

Once you remove `[...]`, you need to also remove the `0` as you need `{2,}` to match 2 or more occurrences. See the [limiting quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) reference.

Use

```
.Pattern = "\s{2,}"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e38vRp/1).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doesn't work with multi-line strings because it smashes newline characters too.

If you need to only crush multiple spaces, like the question title, then use this:

```
''' Replace multiples spaces with one, because one is enough.
Public Function CrushSpaces(ByVal text As String) As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = " {2,}"
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        
        CrushSpaces = .Replace(text, " ")
    End With
End Function
```